# Little CSS Issue

Tags: html, css, wordpress

In this site: http://elegantthemes.com/preview/eStore/?p=20

we can see some vertical lines between 'left-content' and 'widget', and also u can see grey shaded color for the whole widget.

My intention is to make it bigger in size, (left-content) so my content and images can be set perfectly. Due to that greyed color, its looking dirty when I tried to change the width of 'left-column' and 'widget'.

Now my doubts are:

1. I'm thinking to change the width of vertical line between
   'left-content' and 'widget'
2. how can I change the widget grey color to some other color?

Comment: I don't see an actual question. Except for the one about changing the color, but I can't imagine you built a whole site and then don't know how to change a single color..

Comment: @GolezTrol... of course he didn't build a whole site, it's just a WordPress template.

Comment: The Google Chrome tool **Inspect Element** or the Firefox tool *Firebug* would be a GREAT benefit to a) discover these things yourself; b) learn more about website development; and c) ... idk, but they are awesome and USEFUL tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The theme is using a wide background image for `#main-content` to create the appearance of columns. All you need to do is make a new background image for `#main-content` and set the widths like you already did.

You'll probably want to change the background image on `.widgettitle` to match any width or color changes you've made.